# Jetpack Compose AlertDialog Error: "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"

Tags: android, kotlin, text, dialog, android-jetpack-compose

There appear to be an infinite number of explanations for this error on stackoverflow, none of which address my issue.

I am building a compose alert dialog.  I am trying to show a list of options that can change depending on the data.

#### Dialog

```
@Composable
fun OptionSelectComposeDialog(
   vm: OptionSelectDialogViewModel
){
...
val optionList = vm.optionList
Column {
    if (openDialog.value) {
        AlertDialog(
            ...
            text = {
                OptionListDialogContent(optionList)
            },
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

In the `OptionListDialogContent` composable function I'm trying to print out the list, but the `Text` composable is giving an error.

#### `OptionListDialogContent`

```
@Composable
fun OptionListDialogContent(optionList: OptionList?) {

    val optionItemArray = optionList?.getOptionItemArray(null)

    LazyColumn() {
        if (optionItemArray != null) {
            optionItemArray.forEach { optionItem ->
                Text(text = optionItem.toString()) // Error "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspected that the `toString` call on the `optionItem` is throwing this error, so I tried mapping the array to convert the array values to strings and still received this error.

#### `OptionListDialogContent` After converting the array to strings:

```
@Composable
fun OptionListDialogContent(optionList: OptionList?) {

    val optionItemArray = optionList?.getOptionItemArray(null)
    val optionItemStringArray = optionItemArray?.map { it.toString()}?.toTypedArray()

    LazyColumn() {
        if (optionItemStringArray != null) {
            optionItemStringArray.forEach { optionItem ->
                Timber.d("This is working? - optionItemArray.size: %s", optionItemArray.size)
                Text(text = optionItem) // Error "@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone see where the issue is? (I have verified that `optionItemArray` is not null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is an issue with how I was using LazyColumn.  LazyColumn needs to receive an array size.  There are different ways to do this, but this is how I did it:

```
LazyColumn() {
    if (optionItemStringArray != null) {
        items(optionItemStringArray.size) { i ->
            Row() {
                Text(text = optionItemStringArray[i])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is correct solution, but it's not because "LazyColumn needs to receive an array **size**". The thing is, if you would just call your composables as you tried, it won't be **lazy**. Those `item()` and `items()` functions with composable lambdas just inform LazyColumn about the items and allow it to actually compose them only when it's needed.

Comment: That's interesting. So what would the non-lazy version of this look like?

Comment: That would be a normal `Column`. Inside `Column`, you can use simple for loop and directly call the `Text` composable as you did originally.

Comment: I got the error in the original post by trying to render a Text composable as a direct child of a LazyColumn, rather than wrapping it in an item. I thought the item was unnecessary, but turns out, it wasn't!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put a lazy list(which is in OptionListDialogContent) inside a text field

```
text = {
                OptionListDialogContent(optionList)
       },
```

The parameter needs to be compatible to take a composable function. In this case, the text does not do that.

Comment: So a list of text is not considered text in compose?

Comment: Before you show the text in the list.. You have to use LazyColoumn which is a composable function which wont be understood by the text block

Comment: Ugh. I tried to do a custom dialog and that is doing the same thing.  It seems to be an issue with the LazyColumn.

Comment: it's not . Tell me what you want to achieve.. If you want to achieve that the dialog should be shown you should do ..Let me edit my answer

Comment: Yeah, it turns out the LazyColumn needed different info. It needs to know the array size before you can iterate.